# How to crop 6% off on each side?

Tags: objective-c, ios4, uiimage

I am trying to crop off about 6% of a UIImage. However, it's wanting to revert back to a square. Here's my code:

```
CGRect newSize = CGRectMake(image.size.width * .06, 0.0, image.size.width * 0.89, image.size.height);
CGImageRef tmp = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([image CGImage], newSize);
UIImage *finalImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:tmp];
CGImageRelease(tmp);
```

Please help!

Comment: What do you mean by saying it wants to revert back to a square?

Comment: Did you try logging the sizes before and after? I got different values for the same piece of code. And it was chopped off 6%.

Comment: Yup, the demintions are correct but the image is a square.

Comment: Make sure that it's not your presentation of the image that's wrong.  I had a bug the other day where I'd the rect or view size too long, and it stretched a given image to fit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This article](http://vocaro.com/trevor/blog/2009/10/12/resize-a-uiimage-the-right-way/) is a reference to me when it comes to resizing images in iOS.

Not only he provides a bunch of methods to be used as a category for UIImage, but also explains how to accomplish resizing, cropping, round corners, and more.